# Run two procedure in parallel postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, parallel-processing, etl

I need to run two procedure in parallel once I have entry in audit table. Basically audit table should invoke  both the procedure in parallel.

Currently I am using trigger on audit table to invoke procedure which is running sequentially.

Current process: (time constraints)
Example: audit table A - data insert
Procedure 1 trigger>>> then procedure 2 runs. I have to wait till both procedure executes.

Expecting:
Audit table A - data insert
Procedure 1 and procedure2 starts in parallel. So that time can be saved.

Note: there isn't any dependency on procedure 1 and 2.

Please help/suggest how to achieve this in postgresql.
Because trigger can't run procedure in parallel

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that inside the database.

You could have two daemon processes, each with a database connection and [`LISTEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html)ing on a channel. The trigger would then just [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) the channel, and the two processes start the procedures in parallel.

Of course that would mean that if there are two concurrent inserts, the procedures for the second one would wait for the procedures from the first one to complete, unless you plan something more complicated with several daemons that somehow synchronize.